# Java 8 Stream filter all the values from a map given a list of keys

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, String>`

I want to stream all the values in a `List<String>` I call `keys`.

How can I get this to return the Values from the map?

Map like this:

```
("Frank", "Car")
("Bob", "Bike")
("Jim", "Truck")
```

List of keys i give it:

```
["Frank","Jim"]
```

Expected result:

```
["Car","Truck"]
```

I tried this but it just prints the keys not the values.

```
keys.stream()
    .filter(map::containskey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just check, if keys are present in `Map` and if they are, then you keep them in the result stream. To replace keys with values you can use [`map()`](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-map-examples/)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> cars = new HashMap<>();
    cars.put("Frank", "Car");
    cars.put("Bob", "Bike");
    cars.put("Jim", "Truck");

    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    keys.add("Frank");
    keys.add("Jim");
    List<String> result = keys
            .stream()
            .filter(cars::containsKey)
            .map(cars::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
[Car, Truck]
```

Comment: Or `.map(cars::get).filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Answer (score 5):

Stream and filter the entries:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
      .filter(e -> keys.contains(e.getKey()))
      .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```